# Visual Studio C#, Error 2016, Error 2016: The value specified for the condition is not compatible with the type of the member

Tags: c#, mysql, database, module

I am stuck on developing an app with relational database. I am following the online tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvNs5QYPR2U

At around 3:25 ish, the guy used AddTos function in his Visual Studio 2010, which I cannot find the exact in my VS 2012. However, I found something equivalent, like database.s.Add(item), and it reports confusing error..... Can any one tell me what error this is and how I can solve it.

Here is the details:

All this project is doing is to use a button by clicking which, an item would be added to the table under a database.

As usual, I created a database with four tables:

```
TblProductType
TblProduct
TblTransaction
TblTransactionItem
```

Under "Server Explorer"->"Data Connections" these tables are defined under database called: CoffeeShopDatabase

So here is my code to define a button click on my app 
Apparently, because those four tables are associated through "1 to many" keys, CoffeeShopDatabaseEntities2 becomes the type, that includes variable types/functions that are related to those four tables (ex. TblProducts, etc)

The following code is trying to update the table "TblProduct" with a record

```
{Large Coffee, 1.99M}.
```

So first, I defined a CoffeeShopDatabaseEntities2 type variable called csde; then I set a TblProduct variable product1 as the record to be added; then I add product1 to the

```
csde(a database)>TblProducts()
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012, and am trying to follow a online tutorial using VS 2010. Apparently in the tutorial, the guy used

```
csde.AddToTblProducts(product1);  ---------VS 2010
```

However, I cannot find the equivalent on my 2012 VS, but I ended up finding

```
csde.TblProducts.Add(product1);  ----------VS 2012
```

and use it as substitute, to add record product1 to the TblProduct table from the csde database.

Here is the error I got:

```
Error   2   Error 2016: The value specified for the condition is not
compatible with the type of the member. C:\Users\Support\Documents\Visual Studio
2012\Projects\CoffeeShopProject\CoffeeShopProject\
testCoffeeShopDatabase.edmx 157 17  CoffeeShopProject
```

At the same time, while code is running, the window pops up, I clicked the button, after a while a small white window pops up saying:

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 

testCoffeeShopDatabase.msl(8,12) : error 2016: 
The value specified for the condition is not compatible 
with the type of the member.
```

,pointing at:

```
csde.TblProducts.Add(product1);
```

I am fairly new in C# and always felt nothing I can do when seeing this "evil" white window.... Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CoffeeShopProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CoffeeShopDatabaseEntities2 csde = new CoffeeShopDatabaseEntities2();
            TblProduct product1 = new TblProduct()
            {
                Description = "Large Coffee",
                Price = 1.99M
            };
            csde.TblProducts.Add(product1);
            csde.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```